# How do I filter the thick edges of an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am using the Python image library for some basic image operations. I wish to do detect edges of an image, but only the thick ones.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection There are many algorithms you could use like this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

Answer (score 2):

I think I would start by eroding the image in order to remove the thinner edges, leaving the thicker ones, and then edge detect. See [erosion and dilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472768/implementing-erosion-dilation-in-c-c) - may help.

Comment: Just out of interest, which ersosion kernel/filter did you use?

Comment: i use the following:{(0,1,0),(1,1,1),(0,1,0)}. Please suggest a better method if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling thick edges will get detected as 2 edges - in which case you would have to do non-maximum suppression. Have you tried using a median filter or something which would throw out extremely thin edges? (Smoothing after median filter would suppress the thin edges quite a bit though I am a little unsure as to what would happen to the thick ones.)

Another idea would be to use a Hough Transform and keep the threshold high for the number of votes required to detect an edge/line.

Answer (score 0):

What about rescaling your image to lower resolution and finding edges there?

Then you would recompute position of the edges by scaling back to the original size.

Comment: Hey, i like your idea, but is there any other non-brute method?

Comment: @Vishwanath, this is actually a good "non-brute" technique. Take a look at the cvPyrDown function.  Try applying it once, then performing edge detection on the resultant down-sampled image.

Comment: @Krab, i did try your method, but it does not kill the edges completely. I remember vaguely that opencv had some function to do such a work, can you please help me?